# Android ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception?

Tags: android

```
public class GridAllUserAdapter  extends BaseAdapter{

private LayoutInflater _mInflater = null;
private ArrayList<Object>_alluserlist=null;
private Activity _activity = null;
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = null;
ImageLoader imageLoader=null;


/**
 * @param activity
 * @param itemList
 */
public GridAllUserAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Object> itemList) {
    this._activity = activity;
    this._alluserlist = itemList;

    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(_activity);
    _mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    parentActivity=(TabGroupActivity)_activity.getParent();
}

public int getCount() {
    return _alluserlist.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return _alluserlist.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imgViewFlag;
    public TextView txtViewTitle;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = _mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gridview_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pic_name_txt);
        holder.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo_frameImg);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final AllBean bean=(AllBean)_alluserlist.get(position);
    holder.txtViewTitle.setText(bean.getusername());

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(bean.getprofile_photo(), R.drawable.default_profile_pic, holder.imgViewFlag);
    return convertView;
}

// Filter Class
public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    _alluserlist.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        _alluserlist.addAll(_alluserlist);
    } else {
        for (Object bean : _alluserlist) {
            if (((AllBean) bean).getusername().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                    .contains(charText)) {
                _alluserlist.add(bean);

            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

I have gridview in which data is coming from server. When I am clicking on button, data is showing and suddenly my application stops. It's giving me ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at getview..,adapter..,please help me..

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace

Comment: When you post your questions which has a error then don't forget to stacktrace related to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indicate that you get a crash when you click a data. Since you can see all the list and the data in it, the problem is not with your adapter. You should post your list item click event. You are probably doing something with your _alluserlist array which gives you a crash.

Comment: yes sir.,actully i was setting adapter out of loop,so my application was crashing,thnku so much..:)